# What does "steepening of the U.S. Treasury curve" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "the bonds yield will go up"?

"Let's not forget here: The U.S. expansion, while being soft, is actually pretty mature so the Fed is getting lined up here in preparation for the next downturn. That's why we think they're going to hike rates and we will see a **steepening of the U.S. Treasury curve** and that will be supportive of the U.S. going forward."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/06/26/us-dollar-will-be-actually-strengthen-going-forward.html

Comment: off topic. we don't explain the implications of economic graphs here. You do understand that **curve** alludes  to a graph?

Comment: Which words are in question? *steepening* or *curve*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for economic analysis, and does not appear to be about learning English.

Comment: Have you consulted your dictionary to learn about the verb _steepen,_ and the noun _curve?_ If you read the entire article, the meaning of the phrase in bold is quite clear. If you can't read the entire article, consider the possibility that your choice of English reading matter exceeds your current level of fluency, and that you would be wise to start with less advanced texts.

Comment: I think what people are saying is that on this site, the explanation you can get is the plain English meaning of the words--steepening the curve means the line gets more vertical.  If you want to know the technical meaning or implication, the place to ask would be https://quant.stackexchange.com/, https://economics.stackexchange.com/, or https://money.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi everyone. What I really want to know is when the curve steepens (like the one in the graph provided below by Peter), what does that mean? Does it mean the bonds yield will go up? And luckily, Tom Au has just given us the answer.

Comment: I suggest that this question be migrated to Personal Finance SE (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interest rates on Treasury securities tend to rise based on the lengths of the maturities. So a ten year bond will usually yield more than a two year bond.

The "steepness" of Treasury yields refers to the differences between the yields of bonds of different maturities. The "steepening" of yields means that these differences are going up compared to "before" (say, last week).

Example: Last week, the five year bond yielded 2.0% and the ten year bond yielded 4.0% for a difference of 2.0 percentage points. This week, the five year bond yields 2.5% and the ten year bond yields 5.0% for a difference of 2.5 percentage points. The yield curve (between those two points) is steeper this week than last because 2.5 percentage points > 2.0 percentage points.

If interest rates were the same (say 2.0%) "across the board," the yield curve is said to be "flat."

Answer (score 1):

If you understand that **steepen** is to become more **steep** then

[image]